# case? VHDL2008 matching case statement

Tags: syntax, vhdl

VHDL 2008 introduced a nice feature called "matching case statement".

Should I use "case?" keyword or "case ?" with a space in between also allowed?

It is not clear for me.
Lattice LSE allows both of them. Synplify accepts only the first one.

The definition (section 10.9) from the standard is:

```
case_statement ::=
    [ case_label : ]
    case [ ? ] expression is
        case_statement_alternative
        { case_statement_alternative }
    end case [ ? ] [ case_label ] ;
```

Comment: A BNF production (IEEE Std 1076-2008 1.3.2 Syntactic description) contains lexical element and non-VHDL delimiters used to describe syntax.  The rules for lexical elements are found in 15. Lexical elements, 15.3 Lexical elements, separators and delimiters. There is no requirement that there be a separator between an identifier (here the reserved word case, see 15.10) and a delimiter (here the character '?'). "One or more separators are allowed between any two adjacent lexical elements, before the first of each design unit, or after the last lexical element of a design file."

Comment: Your comment pretend to be answer.

Comment: Note that purportedly Synplify violates the quoted sentence from 15.3 in the first comment. There's every chance that if Synopsys Synplify actually disallows a separator between the reserved word `case`(15.10)  and the delimiter `?` (15.3), that the same holds true for the reserve word `select` and the delimiter `?` in selected signal  assignment (10.5.4) or selected variable assignment (10.6.4).

Answer (score 1):

case? is the keyword. No Space.

Comment: Can you tell me why?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. A separator is not required between an identifier (including a reserved word) and a delimiter. another easy example would be `port(`. IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.3 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters.  There is no lexical element boundary confusion, an identifier (15.4 Identifiers, including a reserved word  (15.10 Reserved words) do not contain a delimiter. (Note that an underscore is not a delimiter.)

Comment: @user1155120 is it mean that "case ?" is wrong keyword?

Comment: There is no rule requiring a separator between identifiers and delimiters, separate lexical elements. The reserved words are listed in IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.10 Reserved words. You won't find any reserved word or other identifier  (!5.4) containing a delimiter (15.3).

Comment: @scary_jeff *@user1155120 Why don't you post an actual answer...* "Should I use "case?" keyword or "case ?" with space in between also allowed?" What, a one word answer *Either*? Note this answer without support can be viewed as opinion.

Comment: @ user1155120 While you seem correct that "?" is a separator, with all implied parsing rules, this is not obvious on the first read of LRM (some got it wrong, and others hesitate, after all). Now I re-read grammar specification, it is the only way to interpret it that makes sense, and it definitely deserves an answer to me.

Comment: @Nipo It's not parsing, it's lexical analysis. Lexemes (lexical elements) and not syntax or semantics (collectively grammar). Lexical tokens are provided as input to syntactical analysis (parsing). Here the question mark is a delimiter (not a separator), a lexical element. The key here is understanding the reserved word **case** and the question mark delimiter are distinct lexical elements.

Answer (score 0):

In the VHDL-2008 Language Reference Manual (IEEE Std 1076-2008) chapter 15.3 it is written that

> One  or  more  separators  are  allowed  between  any  two  adjacent  lexical  elements,  before  the  first  of  each  design unit, or after the last lexical element of a design file. At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal.

A space character is defined in the same chapter as one of the separators. Both the "case" and "[ ? ]" are lexical elements.

So both "case?" and "case ?" are valid. The one you should use is "case?" since that's the one that works with all your tools.